# Update table 1 with data from table 2 after sorting data in table 1

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**Table 1**

```
tbl1_id       tbl1_name       tbl1_location          SymbolAssigned
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1               ABC             UK
2               DEF             US
3               GHI             Brazil
```

**Table 2**

```
tbl2_id       tbl2_symbol       
---------------------------
11               Symb1
12               Symb2
13               Symb3
```

```
<button id='assign'>Assign Symbol</button>
```

First ,I need to sort **Table 1** in Ascending Order of `tbl1_name`.

Second, I need to assign the symbols from **Table 2** based on sorted data in **Table 1** on clicking the **Assign Button**

Example

**After Sorting Table 1**

```
tbl1_id       tbl1_name       tbl1_location
--------------------------------------------
1               ABC             UK
2               DEF             US
3               GHI             Brazil
```

After clicking **Assign Button**

```
tbl1_id       tbl1_name       tbl1_location        SymbolAssigned
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1               ABC             UK                        11
2               DEF             US                        12
3               GHI             Brazil                    13
```

**How can I do this using Mysql**

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to do / say. Do you want to do a `SELECT` (`JOIN`) to the required result? Or do you want to `INSERT` in table_1? Because if you are trying to insert, you have to alter the table firstly (ok, you updated the question). Also, what does the `<button>` have to do with the question?

Comment: Not just sorting but reassigning tbl1_id ? Please add table definitions as text

Comment: @Ergis I want to update Table 1 with data from table 2 after the Assign Button is Clicked

Comment: @P.Salmon No. Only assigning symbols from table 2 to table 1

Comment: But what is the condition to as which symbol belongs to which entity in table_1 ? There must be some business rule

Comment: It's a pity After Sorting Table 1 is the same as raw data.

Comment: @Ergis  1st row of Table 1 belongs to corresponding Symbol of first row in Table 2 and so on

Comment: So the logic is that they link by row number?

Comment: No. there is no row no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table_one https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6LPP.jpg

table_two https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX25L.jpg

query.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_your_thing;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_your_thing()
BEGIN
    DECLARE tbl1_data_loop_done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tbl1_id INT;
    DECLARE tbl1_name, tbl1_location, tbl1_symbol VARCHAR(255);
    
    DECLARE tbl2_id INT;
    DECLARE tbl2_symbol VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE tbl1_data CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM table_one ORDER BY table_one.name ASC;
    DECLARE tbl2_data CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM table_two;
    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET tbl1_data_loop_done = TRUE;
    
    OPEN tbl1_data;
    OPEN tbl2_data;

    tbl1_data_loop:  LOOP

        FETCH tbl1_data INTO tbl1_id, tbl1_name, tbl1_location, tbl1_symbol;
        FETCH tbl2_data INTO tbl2_id, tbl2_symbol;

        IF tbl1_data_loop_done THEN
            LEAVE tbl1_data_loop;
        END IF;

        UPDATE table_one SET symbol_assigned = tbl2_id WHERE id = tbl1_id;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE tbl1_data;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
CALL update_your_thing();
```

table_one after query https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3tfd.jpg

The loop depends how many rows are there in your table_one, then assign table_two id into table_one symbol_assigned.

table_one symbol_assigned will be NULL if table_one has many rows than table_two